# How to can display two distplots next to each other?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am unable to display two distplots next to each other, when plotted alone both work fine.

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.distplot(df_reqd_data_0['Total_Hood_Group_Earnings'], ax=ax1)
plt.show()

sns.distplot(df_reqd_data_0['Total_Partner_Earnings'], ax=ax2 )
plt.show()
```

[image: Image of output i am getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `plot.show()` command *once* after both the `distplot` commands.

Remove the extra `plot.show()`, so that the code looks like this.

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.distplot(df_reqd_data_0['Total_Hood_Group_Earnings'], ax=ax1)

sns.distplot(df_reqd_data_0['Total_Partner_Earnings'], ax=ax2 )
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT:**
Apart from the extra `plt.show()`, I am not sure what is `sns` here. But just to illustrate my point and answer the question posted by the OP:

> *"How to can display two distplots next to each other?"*

try this code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(y)

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(x)

plt.show()
```

and you can see why it works.

Comment: `sns` is the module seaborn, usually imported like so - `import seaborn as sns`. The documentation for the specific plot OP is using is here (if you're interested) https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html